# Number theory problem with many variables in a sequence

Tags: number-theory

Very cool number theory problem I was reading!

Problem: Let $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4$ be positive integers such that the following conditions hold:

• $gcd(a_i, a_j) > 1$ holds for all integers $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$;

• $gcd(a_i, a_j, a_k) = 1$ holds for all integers $1 \leq i < j < k \leq 4$.

Find the smallest possible value of $a_4$.

Solution:

I first realized that each of $a_1, a_2, a_3,$ and $a_4$ were $3$ prime numbers multiplied by each other. This is because if the gcd of $2$ of the numbers must be greater than $1$ and the gcd of $3$ of the numbers must be $1$, each number must be $3$ numbers multiplied by each other ($2$ numbers have $1$ factor similar with another and no $3$ numbers have the same factors) and that each was prime to maintain this condition.

I then started seeking for prime numbers to fit this condition. I realized one fact right here that saved me a lot of time. Since there were $4$ different numbers and they had to fit these conditions, there had to be a total of $6$ different prime numbers used across all $4$ numbers' prime factorizations. Since the problem asked for the **smallest** possible value of $a_4$, we have to use the first $6$ prime numbers across the prime factorizations of the $4$ numbers. I am then now stuck on which $3$ prime numbers of each have to go to which number.

I am thinking that I will have to guess and check where to put $2, 3, 5, 7, 11,$ and $13$ into the prime factorizations of the $4$ numbers. Each number must have $3$ different prime numbers used in its prime factorization and each pair of $2$ numbers must have exactly one prime factor in common.

Please help me if there is a different way to solve this problem or if guessing and checking is the only way. I feel like guessing an checking is the best way. Also, I need help on what numbers to guess and check next to find $a_4$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 to your query for very good work shown.  Although I could be mistaken, I see no flaw in your analysis or way to improve your analysis.  My thinking is that the 4 numbers have $\binom{4}{2}$ *intersections*, where each common denominator intersection must be both $> 1$ and mutually exclusive from the other intersections.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you and yes they have 4 choose 2 intersections which is another way to write what I said and probably a better way but I was trying to explain the claims a little better but thank you so much!

Comment: Adding on user2661923’s comment, I recommend for visualization that you draw a tetrahedron, and place one prime number on every edge, and compute, for each vertex, the product of the numbers on the neighboring edges. This gives you every possible set $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$.

Comment: @Mindlack that's actually a very good idea. I didn't think about doing that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your analysis, and it turns out to be easy to find the best arrangement by guessing, and then showing that the guess is correct.

First assume that we will never have $11$ and $13$ in the same group, so $2$ of the groups contain $11$, and the other two contain $13$.

Assume also that we will do best to keep $5$ and $7$ separate.  Now our $4$ groups contain $$5,11\\7,11\\5,13\\7,13$$

The largest product is $7\cdot13$, so we make our last assumption: the third number in the final group should be $2$.  Now the second $2$ can't go with $7$ or $13$, so it must go in the first group, and we have

$$2\cdot5\cdot11=110\\
3\cdot7\cdot11=231\\
3\cdot5\cdot13=195\\
2\cdot7\cdot13=182$$
with maximum $231$.

Now to validate our assumptions.  If $11$ and $13$ are in the same group, the product would be at least $2\cdot11\cdot13=186>231$, so the first assumption is valid.

If $5$ and $7$ were in the same group, the product would be at least $5\cdot7\cdot11>231,$ and the second assumption is valid.

Finally putting $3$ in the last group would give $3\cdot7\cdot13>231$ and the third assumption is valid.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! The guessing and checking method seems a bit slow but it gets the job done. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Iamaperson It took longer to write the explanation than to do it, or at least, it seemed that way to me.

Comment: yes, guessing and checking is easy in theory. It just takes a little longer than usual methods.